# Perturbation of Hamiltonian in the presences of an EM field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I am looking into the Hamiltonian of a charged particle in an EM field. The Hamiltonian is given by: 
$$\hat H= \frac{1}{2m} (\vec p-q \vec A)^2+e \phi \tag{1}$$
where $\vec p=m \vec v+q \vec A$ is the conjugate momentum and for linearly polarized, monochromatic light $\phi=\phi_0$ the electric potential in the presence of no EM field. Thus in theory we could write the Hamiltonian as:
$$\hat H=\frac{1}{2} m \vec v^2 +e \phi_0\tag{2}$$
and claim that their is no perturbation due to the EM field. However, this is not done and instead (1) is expanded to give:
$$\hat H= \color{green}{\frac{1}{2m} \vec p^2+e \phi_0}+ \color{red}{\frac{1}{2m} \left( q^2\vec A^2+2q \vec p \cdot \vec A  \right)}\tag{3}$$
where the green text is the $\color{green}{\text{unperturbed}}$ Hamiltonian and and the red is the $\color{red}{\text{pertubed}}$ due to the EM field. But does $\vec p$ depend explicit on $\vec A$ and hence so does the green portion of equation (3) how can this then be the unperturbed Hamiltonian rather then that given in (2).

Comment: you are using Hamitonian mechanics, not Lagrangian mechanics. Here, $\vec v$ means nothing, it is undefined. More precisely, you can it understand as $v=v(p,A)$, so that it is not independent of these operators. It makes no sense (read, it is useless) to write the Hamitonian in terms of velocities.

Comment: The Hamiltonian (2) has explicit dependence on time, for example, in the coordinate representation $\vec{v}=-i\hbar\nabla-(e/c)\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)$, so it cannot be considered as unperturbed.